# Populating password input fields on client

Tags: razor, passwords

this question has been posed in many flavours, but no one fits my needs.
I'm working on a partially complete Razor project; the original developer has left our office, and he wasn't much concerned about securing password fields, as he left all of them in clear.
These passowrd fields authorize several aspects (Ftp primary and secondary access, Ftp on AS400 and mail sending), so nothing related with login/submit forms. When I changed these fields from text to password, they revert to blank fields, regardless the content of the View Model, and this should be the correct behaviour, as per the numerous answers I've seen googlin around.
My problem is this: the user needs to know at least if a password has been configured (seeing a string of * or any other mask character the browser use), so I need to show him that value to let him know if the service is configured, and the best would be to let him also reveal the password to check if it's correct. The option to not update the particular field in the DB if it's left blank is not an option.
This site works only on Intranet, so there is no concern about hackers monitoring the connection or similar.
I've tried all (I think) the possible combinations, including building the input element manually through html, using the @Html.TextFor and @Html.PasswordFor helpers, decorating the corrisponding member in the view model with [DataType(DataType.Password)]. The data is binded when the page is loaded, so no ajax calls help me retrieving data.
I'm relatively new to Razor, as my last two projects are entirely in PHP.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no other solution found than issuing an ajax call to a dedicated HttpGet controller method to retrieve only the password fiels, then populating the dedicated fields when the controller returns the object containing all the password I need.